# Why won't my graph change?

Tags: manipulate

I'm trying to "animate" the change of distance traveled with respect to time.
Here's a piece of code:

```
S1i[t_, V1i_] = t*V1i;
Manipulate[
  Plot[S1i[t, V1i], {t, 0, 10}],
  {t, 0, 10}]
```

But i just get a graph with a straight line, but when i try to manipulate `t`, nothing changes. 
After that i tried with manipulating `V1i` and i get the same problem.

I am new to Mathematica so I'm sorry if the question is too simple.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I had apparently forgot to put `:=` when defining the function, so i did succeed to manipulate `V1i`, but i still stuck with `t`.

Comment: `Manipulate[Plot[S1i[t, V1i], {t, 0, tmax},
  PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 100}},
  AxesLabel -> {"time", "distance"}],
 {{V1i, 5}, 0, 10, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{tmax, 10}, 0.1, 10, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]`

Answer (score 1):

```
S1i[t_, V1i_] := t*V1i;
Manipulate[Plot[S1i[t, V1i], {t, 0, 10},
  PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 100}}], {V1i, 0, 10}]
```